# Learning resources for GDAL?

Tags: gdal, references

I quite often get stuck trying to solve particular problems, or getting syntaxes right.

Apart from the details provided in the links on [GDAL Utilities](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_utilities.html), does anyone know of any 3rd party resources/manuals explaining it in a bit more user friendly way?

Answer (score 6):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
>   because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
>   and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure.  It
>   should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
>   type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
>   site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
>   to do so by editing this answer.

---

- This book will probably serve as a good reference: [Geospatial Power Tools – GDAL/OGR Command Line Utilities](http://www.locatepress.com/books/gdalogr-book-update)
- A compilation of gdal help links from cartotalk: 
  http://www.cartotalk.com/index.php?showtopic=5144

[This website](http://opengeoportal.org/software/resources/gdal-and-open-source-geoprocessing-tutorials/) lists out several options for you to consider...

- Learning GDAL and Open-source Tutorials
- GDAL.org
- OSGeo Trac

Check out the options documented in [Seeking Open Source Training Materials?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13982/open-source-training-materials), which address open source training in general.

Answer (score 1):

Book:

Python Geospatial Development - Second Edition, by Eric Westra

It's a nice tutorial for processing spatial data with GDAL Python library mainly.

Of course GDAL website is a nice source of informations: http://www.gdal.org

Answer (score -1):

One of best resources to start working on GDAL is the [Cheat sheet for GDAL/OGR command-line geodata tools](https://github.com/dwtkns/gdal-cheat-sheet), and below you can find a list of links for diving deeply:

http://live.osgeo.org/en/quickstart/gdal_quickstart.html

https://github.com/nvkelso/geo-how-to/wiki/OGR-to-reproject,-modify-Shapefiles

ftp://ftp.remotesensing.org/gdal/presentations/OpenSource_Weds_Andre_CUGOS.pdf

http://developmentseed.org/blog/2009/jul/30/using-open-source-tools-make-elevation-maps-afghanistan-and-pakistan/

http://linfiniti.com/2010/12/a-workflow-for-creating-beautiful-relief-shaded-dems-using-gdal/

http://linfiniti.com/2009/09/clipping-rasters-with-gdal-using-polygons/

http://nautilus.baruch.sc.edu/twiki_dmcc/bin/view/Main/OGR_example

http://www.gdal.org/frmt_hdf4.html

http://planetflux.adamwilson.us/2010/06/modis-processing-with-r-gdal-and-nco.html

http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/FAQRaster

http://www.mikejcorey.com/wordpress/2011/02/05/tutorial-create-beautiful-hillshade-maps-from-digital-elevation-models-with-gdal-and-mapnik/

http://dirkraffel.com/2011/07/05/best-way-to-merge-color-relief-with-shaded-relief-map/

http://gfoss.blogspot.com/2008/06/gdal-raster-data-tips-and-tricks.html

http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/gdal-dev-Dissolve-shapefile-using-GDAL-OGR-td5036930.html

https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/terrain-data/

https://gist.github.com/ashaw/0862ec044c45b9aa3c76

https://github.com/gina-alaska/dans-gdal-scripts

**Reference:**
https://github.com/dwtkns/gdal-cheat-sheet